# Active Record sort by min value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a few models, City, Hotel, and Room. City `has_many` hotels, hotels `has_many` rooms. Each room has a price. I'm trying to sort by the lowest price room, asc and desc.

In my results, I'm also showing the lowest price for a hotel. I'm able to successfully sort by price ass with this

`City.first.includes(hotel: :rooms).order("rooms.price asc")`

But since I want to always show the lowest price, this doesn't work if I want to sort high to low since it sorts by the highest room price for a hotel.

Is there a way to sort by a hotels minimum room price? If I try to order by `MIN(rooms.price) desc` I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

City model

```
attr_accessible :name
has_many :hotels
```

Hotel model

```
attr_accessible :city_id, :name
has_many :rooms
belongs_to :city
```

City model

```
attr_accessible :hotel_id, :name, :price
belongs_to :hotel
```

Please have a try with

```
@rooms = Room.includes([:hotel => [:city]]).select('hotel_id, MIN(price) AS price').group('hotel_id').order('MIN(rooms.price) ASC')
```

In your view file

```
<% @rooms.each do |room| %>
 <div>
   <div><%= room.hotel.name</div>
   <div><%= room.hotel.city%></div>
   <div><%= room.price%></div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to select hotels for a specific city?